# How to remove css properties in the last level elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this [code snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/hkL0xjvv/5/). Due to the limited right with the html generator, I can't do anything with the html, only insert some css and javascript code.

I want to do 2 things:

- Remove the plus sign from last level element (`class="project child leaf "`)
- change plus to minus sign according to click. I know that I have to write `toggle` to `addClass` or `removeClass` but have no idea how to implement :(

Please help me.

```js
$(function() {
  $('li.child>ul.projects li.child').children('li>ul').hide();
  //'li.child>ul.projects li.child').children('li>ul:first').show();

});
$("li").on("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).children('ul').toggle();

});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul > li.child:before {
  content: "+";
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -1.1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Projects</h2>

<div id="projects-index">
  <ul class='projects root'>
    <li class='root'>
      <div class='root'><a class="project root parent " href="/redmine/projects/abc">Company projects</a></div>
      <ul class='projects '>
        <li class='child'>
          <div class='child'><a class="project child parent " href="/redmine/projects/abc">A-1.abc</a></div>
          <ul class='projects '>
            <li class='child'>
              <div class='child'><a class="project child parent " href="/redmine/projects/a-research">A. research</a></div>
              <ul class='projects '>
                <li class='child'>
                  <div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/test-rds">1. rds</a></div>
                </li>
                <li class='child'>
                  <div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/test-bgx">test-bgx</a></div>
                </li>
                <li class='child'>
                  <div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/3d">3. 3d</a></div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class='child'>
              <div class='child'><a class="project child parent " href="/redmine/projects/b-shop">B. shop</a></div>
              <ul class='projects '>
                <li class='child'>
                  <div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/du">1. DU</a></div>
                </li>
                <li class='child'>
                  <div class='child'><a class="project child leaf my-project" href="/redmine/projects/d2m">D2m</a></div>
                </li>
                <li class='child'>
                  <div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/m2s">3. m2s</a></div>
                </li>
                <li class='child'>
                  <div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/korean">4. korean</a></div>
                </li>
                <li class='child'>
                  <div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/2msms">6. C2msms</a></div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class='child'>
              <div class='child'><a class="project child parent " href="/redmine/projects/c-others">C. Others</a></div>
              <ul class='projects '>
                <li class='child'>
                  <div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/summary">1. summary</a></div>
                </li>
                <li class='child'>
                  <div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/group">2. group</a></div>
                </li>
                <li class='child'>
                  <div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/yearly">3. yearly</a></div>
                </li>
                <li class='child'>
                  <div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/prj">prj</a></div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant code directly in the question body.

Comment: Please wait, I'm not really familiar with this feature so it will take a while...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('li').click(function(){
    if($(this).has('ul').length) {
      $(this).children('ul').toggleClass('show');
      $(this).not('.root').toggleClass('sbl');
    }
  }).click(function(e){
    return false;
  })
  $('li').each(function(e){
    if(!$(this).has('ul').length) {
      $(this).addClass('sbl');
    }
  })
})
```

```css
 ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li:not(.root) ul{
  display: none;
}

ul > li.child:before {
  content: "+";
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -1.1em;
  cursor: pointer;
} 

.show {
  display: inline-block!important;
}

.sbl:before {
  content: '-'!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Projects</h2>
<div id="projects-index">
  <ul class='projects root'>
    <li class='root'>
      <div class='root'><a class="project root parent " href="/redmine/projects/abc">Company projects</a></div>
      <ul class='projects '>
        <li class='child'>
          <div class='child'><a class="project child parent " href="/redmine/projects/abc">A-1.abc</a></div>
          <ul class='projects '>
            <li class='child'>
              <div class='child'><a class="project child parent " href="/redmine/projects/a-research">A. research</a></div>
              <ul class='projects '>
                <li class='child'>
                  <div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/test-rds">1. rds</a></div>
                </li>
                <li class='child'>
                  <div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/test-bgx">test-bgx</a></div>
                </li>
                <li class='child'>
                  <div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/3d">3. 3d</a></div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class='child'>
              <div class='child'><a class="project child parent " href="/redmine/projects/b-shop">B. shop</a></div>
              <ul class='projects '>
                <li class='child'>
                  <div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/du">1. DU</a></div>
                </li>
                <li class='child'>
                  <div class='child'><a class="project child leaf my-project" href="/redmine/projects/d2m">D2m</a></div>
                </li>
                <li class='child'>
                  <div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/m2s">3. m2s</a></div>
                </li>
                <li class='child'>
                  <div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/korean">4. korean</a></div>
                </li>
                <li class='child'>
                  <div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/2msms">6. C2msms</a></div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class='child'>
              <div class='child'><a class="project child parent " href="/redmine/projects/c-others">C. Others</a></div>
              <ul class='projects '>
                <li class='child'>
                  <div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/summary">1. summary</a></div>
                </li>
                <li class='child'>
                  <div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/group">2. group</a></div>
                </li>
                <li class='child'>
                  <div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/yearly">3. yearly</a></div>
                </li>
                <li class='child'>
                  <div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/prj">prj</a></div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome!  Work like a charm! Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

To remove the `+` from the last child Use the `:last-of-type` pseudo selector after your existing style rule that adds it. To alter the symobl on the click - toggle a clas and have the `:before` content for that class be `-`. I have only removed the `+` in the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $('li.child>ul.projects li.child').children('li>ul').hide();
  //'li.child>ul.projects li.child').children('li>ul:first').show();

});
$("li").on("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).children('ul').toggle();

});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul > li.child:before {
  content: "+";
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -1.1em;
}

ul > li.child:last-of-type:before {
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Projects</h2>

<div id="projects-index">
  <ul class='projects root'>
    <li class='root'>
      <div class='root'><a class="project root parent " href="/redmine/projects/abc">Company projects</a></div>
      <ul class='projects '>
        <li class='child'>
          <div class='child'><a class="project child parent " href="/redmine/projects/abc">A-1.abc</a></div>
          <ul class='projects '>
            <li class='child'>
              <div class='child'><a class="project child parent " href="/redmine/projects/a-research">A. research</a></div>
              <ul class='projects '>
                <li class='child'>
                  <div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/test-rds">1. rds</a></div>
                </li>
                <li class='child'>
                  <div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/test-bgx">test-bgx</a></div>
                </li>
                <li class='child'>
                  <div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/3d">3. 3d</a></div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class='child'>
              <div class='child'><a class="project child parent " href="/redmine/projects/b-shop">B. shop</a></div>
              <ul class='projects '>
                <li class='child'>
                  <div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/du">1. DU</a></div>
                </li>
                <li class='child'>
                  <div class='child'><a class="project child leaf my-project" href="/redmine/projects/d2m">D2m</a></div>
                </li>
                <li class='child'>
                  <div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/m2s">3. m2s</a></div>
                </li>
                <li class='child'>
                  <div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/korean">4. korean</a></div>
                </li>
                <li class='child'>
                  <div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/2msms">6. C2msms</a></div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class='child'>
              <div class='child'><a class="project child parent " href="/redmine/projects/c-others">C. Others</a></div>
              <ul class='projects '>
                <li class='child'>
                  <div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/summary">1. summary</a></div>
                </li>
                <li class='child'>
                  <div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/group">2. group</a></div>
                </li>
                <li class='child'>
                  <div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/yearly">3. yearly</a></div>
                </li>
                <li class='child'>
                  <div class='child'><a class="project child leaf " href="/redmine/projects/prj">prj</a></div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
```

Comment: Thank, but this remove that last element "+" as well, you can see  "3. 3d" or the last "prj" for example.